# Playing a card problem

Tags: probability

there is a simple question that is making me puzzled.

Two guys M and N both have at hand exactly 7 red cards and 5 black cards. Now, M draw a card from N. Secondly, N draw a card from M. Which is the probability that both guys have 7 red cards and 5 black cards at the end of the process?

Well, at the end of the first operation, two situations may occur, namely:

1) M has 8 red cards and 5 black cards, while N has 6 red cards and 5 black cards or

2) M has 7 red cards and 6 black cards, while N has 7 red cards and 4 black cards

Now, apply the second operation. To have the wanted configurations, we must have:

1) probability$=\frac{8}{13}$;

2) probability$=\frac{6}{13}$.

How do I evaluate the total probability? Is it $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{8}{13}+\frac{6}{13})=\frac{7}{13}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about the probabilities for the second step, but you have to "weigh" them with the probability that each situation occurs after the first step. To get to 1 we need M to draw a red ($\frac{7}{12}$) and for 2 he has to draw a black card ($\frac{5}{12}$) so in total we get:

$$\frac{7}{12}\frac{8}{13} + \frac{5}{12}\frac{6}{13} = \frac{56+30}{12\times 13}=\frac{43}{78}$$

You could see it as the total probability $$P(\text{success})= P(\text{success}|I)P(I)+ P(\text{success}|II)P(II)$$

where II is the event of getting to to situation 2, and ditto I for 1.

Comment: May you write a complete answer please?

Comment: @TheWanderer what's incomplete about it?

Comment: Well, you are computing the total probability? There, the first addend is 7/12 8/13. How do you get 7/12? It depends on the first operation M, is it?

Comment: @TheWanderer see my clarification based on the "Law of total probability".

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin that’s what I said wasn’t it?